# The default UINavigationBar back button with custom image doesn't appear for the first time

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

I'm porting my UI to iOS7. One of the problems I found is that the default back button with customized background doesn't show the background, but only title after pushing the new controller to `UINavigationViewController`. The background shows once I hit the back button and then shows all next times I move back and forth between the controllers. Does anybody know how to resolve it?

Thanks!

UPDATE - adding image: after first push:
[image]

after click and push again:

[image]

Note - the arrow is a custom stretchetable image, that is set by using:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationController class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarButtons_back"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:17 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationController class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarButtons_backPress"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:17 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: It would be great if you put image.

Comment: did you try by putting that code in the app delegate?

Comment: It is there already, also pay attention, that the customization is on appearance, not on the specific instance of UIBarButtonItem

Comment: See [iOS 7 custom back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824887/ios-7-custom-back-button). One option is to ditch the background images (which is more iOS7-ish anyways), or there is a patch at that link which you could use to fix it.

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009879/uibarbuttonitem-appearance-trouble-in-ios-7-could-this-be-an-apple-bug?rq=1. Apparently there is a bug, that was filled for Apple for this problem