# Custom Back button with image for iOS6+

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to have a custom back button with image only (no text).

I'm aware that there could be slightly ifferent solution for iOS7 and iOS6. For now I'm not successfull with any.

All I achieved was this:

[image]

White default arrow is still there :(

I used this code:

```
    UIImage *temp = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_back.png"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:temp style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action)];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

Comment: you should set leftbarbuttonitem. And hide BackBarButtonItem

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824887/ios-7-custom-back-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `leftBarBttonItem` for custom back button

```
 UIImage *temp = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_back.png"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
 UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:temp style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action)];
 self navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```