# Background image of back button does not appear before it is touched iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios7

I am experiencing some problems with `[UIBarButtonItem appearance]` for the the back button background image.

Normally (iOS 5 and iOS 6) I was able to set the background image of the back button like this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But at iOS 7 the background image does not appear on the back button. The weird thing is, that the background image actually appears when the back button has been touched once.

I have tried setting the image for all states, to test if iOS 7 was using some kind of new state for an untouched back button, but that does not seem to be the case.

Do you have any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's possible to fix the display glitch with a swizzled method; see my response at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19452709/1754225 .  But some of the other alternatives might be preferable.

Comment: Unfortunately I am also facing the same problem. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No I didn't. I had to create a custom back-button as a `UIButton` and set it as `leftBarButtonItem` to work around it. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I searched for this problem and found that you are not the only one to have the same problem. There are many others who face the same issue with `UIAppearance`. These are the proofs (*to explain you to your client*) :

1. [UIBackButton Background Image not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18835672/1603072)
2. [Back button is not visible in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18950658/1603072)

---

In this case, what you can do is to follow the Answer provided in the 2nd Link.

You can either set the `backIndicatorImage` property on `UINavigationBar` to a custom image or you can change the color of the `backIndicatorImage` by setting the `tintColor` property on `UINavigationBar`.

You can create a custom `UIBarButtonItem` and manually assign it as `UINavigationItem`'s `leftBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution which will make the background appear correctly on iOS7 is at [OS 7 custom back button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452709/1754225).  It swizzles a method to fix the Apple bug (which is that they forget to call setNeedsDisplay on the private view when the background image is changed).  Going borderless is probably better, if possible, but swizzling does work.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the tint color of the button. There is some issue in iOS 7 for UIBarButton

Comment: Can you give some evidence for the claim? I am having the same issue, and I have to explain it to the client. That's why I am asking you :)

Comment: first try ti yourself and if it works than u can explain it to client as well

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a really nice solution that works under ios5+ here:

[Back button item strangely disappearing under iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236410/back-button-strangely-disappearing-in-uinavigationcontroller-but-keeps-working/19238312#19238312)

Answer (score 0):

To work with ios7 you need to use

```
    UIImage *backButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back" resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
if ([UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setBackIndicatorImage:)]) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:backButton];
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:backButton];
}else{
//ios 5 and 6 code
}
```